# Change parent div if input radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 radio inputs, that are wrapped in div so that they look like buttons instead of the default radio circle input, on click I am replacing the button text for checked icon. Now on validation if it fails I am returning the old value, and would like to again replace the text of the button for icon checked if the radio input was checked.

This is the script for the click action:

```
$('.Image-input__input-wrapper').click(function() {
      $( '.plan-text-icon-toggle' ).replaceWith( '<span class="plan-text-icon-toggle">This is what I need</span>' )
      $(this).find( '.plan-text-icon-toggle' ).replaceWith( '<span class="plan-text-icon-toggle"><i class="ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>' );
  });
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="Image-input__input-wrapper">
    <span class="plan-text-icon-toggle">This is what I need</span>
    <input class="Image-input__input" type="radio" name="plan" value="player" {{ old('plan')=="player" ? 'checked='.'"'.'checked'.'"' : '' }}>
</div>
```

Now I would like to to do same for on page load if the button was checked already, but not sure how to do it?

**Update**
I have tried with adapting the suggestion in the answers:

```
    function checkinput(elem) {
    var parent = elem.parent(), 
        checked = elem.is(':checked');

    $('.radio').removeClass('active').html('This is what I need');

    if (checked) {
        parent.addClass('active').html('Checked');
    }
}

// apply style on change
$('[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    checkinput(elem);
});

// apply style on load
var elem = $('[type=radio]:checked');
checkinput(elem);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1du1r3bz/8/) is the full example. But it is not working.

Comment: One easier alternative is to use css classes and show / hide depending on the class rather than replacing the content(s) of your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use input radio and just change the style with CSS. Look the example bellow:

```js
function checkinput(elem) {
    var parent = elem.parent(), 
        checked = elem.is(':checked');

    $('.radio').removeClass('active');

    if (checked) {
        parent.addClass('active');
    }
}

// apply style on change
$('[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    checkinput(elem);
});

// apply style on load
var elem = $('[type=radio]:checked');
checkinput(elem);
```

```css
.radio .on {
  display: none;
}

.radio.active .off {
  display: none;
}

.radio.active .on {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label class="radio">
    <span class="on">Message when checked</span>
    <span class="off">Message when unchecked</span>
    <input type="radio" name="my-radio" value="1">
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="radio">
    <span class="on">Message when checked</span>
    <span class="off">Message when unchecked</span>
    <input type="radio" name="my-radio" value="2">
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label class="radio">
    <span class="on">Message when checked</span>
    <span class="off">Message when unchecked</span>
    <input type="radio" name="my-radio" value="3" checked>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but I should check on page load, not on input change, I already do that with my script

Comment: I've changed the example.

Comment: But how would I do that on my example, since I am having text in the button as well and need to change that too, and not just class?

Comment: I have tried with changing your answer to this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1du1r3bz/5/) , but it is not working.

Comment: Run again the snipped. The js logic still the same but I've change the HTML/CSS to display/hide the messages.